# Facebook Canvas App using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, facebook, canvas, facebook-canvas

I want to create an application on Facebook and I will host it on our server to be used from Facebook Canvas.

I was thinking of creating the web app with Angular.JS but one of my friends told me that my web app must be drawn inside a `<canvas>` html tag or I will not have the full functionality of Facebook integration.

So this is my question, do I have to draw my elements inside a `<canvas>`? or I can use other html tags with some basic animation?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do NOT need to use HTML5 Canvas. There are "Canvas Apps", but there is no relation to HTML5 Canvas. Please check out the docs for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs

There are only a few things that are not possible without a Canvas App. For example, you can only use Notifications with a Canvas App, or you can only use `invitable_friends` in a gane with Canvas implementation. Don´t worry about those before reading the docs.

Comment: Thanks mate, I have read the docs and I didn't find anything related to HTML5 canvas, but my friend insisted that I should use one, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Why do you believe your friend, if _they_ can’t show any proof for what they are claiming …?